# Module build failed (from ./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js):

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, sass, node-modules

```
ERROR in ./src/Sass/categories.sass (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[3]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[4]!./src/Sass/categories.sass)

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js):
Error: resolve-url-loader: error processing CSS
  aSourceMapConsumer.originalPositionFor is not a function
  at SourceMapGenerator.<anonymous> (C:\D-Drive\React\Caurse Practical\Project\capstone\crwn-clothing\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-generator.js:204:45)
    at encodeError (C:\D-Drive\React\Caurse Practical\Project\capstone\crwn-clothing\node_modules\resolve-url-loader\index.js:287:12)
    at onFailure (C:\D-Drive\React\Caurse Practical\Project\capstone\crwn-clothing\node_modules\resolve-url-loader\index.js:228:14)
```

i want to use sass package in my react app

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, could you expand on the error by providing a little more code. Does error message points to a file in your `src/`  directory? Have you already installed `node-sass`? Could you share the contents of your `package.json` file and `categories.sass` file (if you have made this in your app)?

Comment: Thanks you for your intrest but this problem is solved after just remove and install sass using npm so there is no any error now